# Is there a way to make an scrolling animation (swipe left then right) in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, scroll

Let's say, if there are 10 buckets in the tray (horizontal), buckets are visible starting from bucket 1, bucket 0 is hidden. We want an educational animation: after app started, tray auto scroll to index 0, then bounce a little bit, then scroll back to index 1.

Wondering if there is a way to use `RecyclerView` to implement this feature?

Thanks!

Methods I've tried (to test it, I implement those code blocks to method `OnDataChange`, and use `uiExecutor` to execute them):

```
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
```

```
// will scroll to 1 automatically, no animation 
recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0) 
recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(1)
```

```
// will scroll to 0, never come back
recyclerView.postDelayed({
    recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0)
    recyclerView.postDelayed({ recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(1) }, 2000)
},2000)
```

```
// will scroll to 0, never come back
val onScrollListener: OnScrollListener = object : OnScrollListener() {
    override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int){
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
        val firstItemVisible = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
        if (firstItemVisible == 0) {
            recyclerView.post { recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(1)}
        }
    }
}
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(onScrollListener)
recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0)
```